# How to identify syntax keywords in vim?

Tags: vim

Is there a general method to identify whether the current word is a syntax keyword? By syntax keyword, I mean include, struct, int in C, or public, class, static in C++, etc.

Here's the context:

```
let w=expand('<cword>')
if is_syntax_keyword(w)
    ...
endif
```

Comment: Would the "Naming Convensions" section in http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html help?

Comment: Thank you! Finally I solved my problem by combining synIDattr() and syntax naming conversions.

Comment: Awesome ^^ I'll write that as a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This document](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html) has a lot of information about syntax naming conventions - and may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This vimcast: [Creating Color Schemes for Vim](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/creating-colorschemes-for-vim/) explains in detail how to identify the parts of syntax Vim recognizes.

Comment: Check your link - it 404'd for me.